# How to import Firebase data to Bigquery dataset in EU?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have followed Googles instructions successfully on linking Firebase to Bigquery, and that works well. Unfortunately, trying to query this data I get the message that the Dataset is in the US while my other datasets are in the EU. How can I move my current Firebase data to the EU, and how can I make sure that all new Firebase data is streamed to a dataset in the EU?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy datasets between regions using `BigQuery Data Transfer Service`:

```
bq mk --transfer_config \
      --project_id=myproject \
      --data_source=region_data_copy \
      --target_dataset=dataset_eu \
      --display_name='CopyDataset' \
      --params='{"source_dataset_id":"dataset_us","source_project_id":"myproject"}'
```

**Documentation link:**
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#bq